# Скачать видео, если есть субтитры

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, crawling

Встроена ли возможность в [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) следующего толка? Требуется скачать видео из канала, если у него есть субтитры. Скачать все видео из канала можно легко. Но что, если нужно сначала сделать анализ видео, и лишь потом скачать его. Как это осуществить? Хочется делать это тремя запросами запросом. В youtube-dl это происходит в четыре запроса:

- выкачиваем страницу с видео
- выкачиваем субы
- выкачиваем страницу с видео
- выкачиваем видео

Три запроса:

- выкачиваем страницу с видео
- выкачиваем субы
- выкачиваем видео

Можно ли с помощью youtube-dl вытащить комменты? Ручками я это научился делать, а скрапить в едином стиле через youtube-dl не понимаю, как. Научите, пожалуйста, если кто-нибудь умеет.

Сразу скажу, что через консоль это сделать вряд ли получится. Нужно лезть в исходники и исследовать то, как осуществляются вызовы функций для скачивания. Исследовав относительно глубоко исходный код, я так и не смог осуществить этого. Требуются знания человека, который очень хорошо знаком с youtube-dl.

Comment: Если там целое видео выкачивается, то зачем жалеть трафик на лишний запрос за страницей?

Comment: Если у вас выкачивается 10000 видео? Тогда это оказывается дорого.

Comment: В принципе, я в процессе написания crawler`а. Поэтому, как только его допишу, выложу сюда в качестве ответа. Другое дело, что пока что он использует функционал youtube dl

Answer (score 2):

[мой пример титров](https://My-video.vova2020.repl.co)Ты можешь проще сделать, для этого тебе нужен спец-файл с расширением .vtt, в ньом ты можешь задать свои субтитры в видео:
HTML:

```
    <video controls>
     <source src="видео" type="video/формат">
     <track kind="subtitles" src="ru.vtt" srclang="ru" label="русский">
    </video>
```

Файл ru.vtt:

```
    WEBVTT
    
    00.00.000 --> 00.30.000
     Текст субтитра
    00.30.000 --> 01.00.000
     Текст субтитра
```

Отступ перед "Текст субтитра" обязателен, 00.30.000 - 00 минут 30 секунд 000 миллисекунд

Answer (score 0):

Есть такие параметры:

```
--write-sub                      Write subtitle file
--write-auto-sub                 Write automatically generated subtitle file
                                 (YouTube only)
--all-subs                       Download all the available subtitles of the
                                 video
--list-subs                      List all available subtitles for the video
--sub-format FORMAT              Subtitle format, accepts formats
                                 preference, for example: "srt" or
                                 "ass/srt/best"
--sub-lang LANGS                 Languages of the subtitles to download
                                 (optional) separated by commas, use --list-
                                 subs for available language tags
```

в данном случае тебе нужно будет пробивать через параметр `--list-subs`

Источник:

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/#subtitle-options

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: Нет, так не работает. Нужно так: * Обкачка страницы с видео для вытаскивания субов, * Обкачка страницы с видео для вытаскивания видео. Это плохо. Хочется за один проход это делать. Я практически на 100% уверен, что покопавшись в исходниках, можно найти решение. Но я, пролистав и разобрав много кода, не смог понять как это сделать. Я не дошёл до того момента, где формируется url видео. Если есть гуру youtube-dl, был бы признателен за ответ.